# CRM 2016 Bing Map control does not shows location in form load

Tags: dynamics-crm, bing-maps

When I open an Account Entity, The map is not loaded properly despite of having proper address. But when I refresh the form using refresh button of browser, the map is shown properly. Below are the screen shots. Does anybody have idea about it ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am facing this problem with IE browser only.

Comment: I'd get in touch with Microsoft Support, looks like a bug in CRM+IE

Answer (score 0):

There could be one of two possible issues:

If you are using the on premise version of CRM, the Bing Maps key being used may be a basic key. If so, then it will be subject to rate limiting. If this occurs it is possible that from time to time a geocode request will not process. If this were to occur, then the map in CRM would not update. To fix this, you would need an enterprise Bing Maps key. You can contact the licensing team at maplic@microsoft.com

If you are using CRM online, then an enterprise Bing Maps key is more than likely being used and the issue is with the implementation of Bing Maps by CRM. In this case, contact the CRM support team: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/dynamics-online-support.aspx

Comment: I am using a developer key for bing maps. It works for other cases in another test organization. Is it possible to have different behaviour for the same bing map key ?

Comment: Ok, two possible issues. If using a developer key, it is more than likely that your request was rate limited. If you check the network traffic you should see the geocoding request made through the Location API. If it completes with a 200 response, look at the response header, and see if there is a parameter called X-MS-BM-WS-INFO  set to 1. If there is, then the request was rate limited. If you don't get a 200 response, then there is a different issue with the request.

Comment: I am unable to find a proper geocoding request url. I can see request to webservices and webresources but unable to find proper geocoding request. Can you please provide me the sample how this request looks like? Or when requested from CRM, are there other things in consideration ?

Comment: The beginning of the URL should look like this: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations